# Почему Regex не находит в строке?

Tags: c#, winforms, парсер

Я делаю такой проект, в котором вводишь сколько долларов, и потом программа говорит тебе доллары в рублях. Я использую **WebClient**. Я написал что **WebClient** выполняет метод *DownloadDataAsync*, а потом написал событие *DownloadDataCompleted*. После, я создал метод в котором всё это обрабатывается. Я добавил Regex. С помощью символа .*? я попробовал найти из самой страницы **cbr.ru** всё что нужно. Я выбрал вот эту часть страницы:

```html
<tr>
   <td class="">840</td>
   <td class="">USD</td>
   <td class="">1</td>
   <td class="">Доллар США</td>
   <td class="">77,2759</td>
</tr>
```

Когда я начал выполнять код, то, при выводе он не может найти группу( **(.*?)** )
Вот сам код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PARSER
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DataCallback(Object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] data = (byte[])e.Result;
            string textData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            Match match = Regex.Match(textData, "<tr><td class=\"\">840</td><td class=\"\">USD</td><td class=\"\">1</td><td class=\"\">Доллар США</td><td class=\"\">(.*?)</td></tr>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            richTextBox1.Text = "lol" + match.Groups[1].ToString();
        }
        async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double dollars = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(DataCallback);
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.s.: я хочу сначала получить цену доллара, потом уже из **textBox1** получить правильное произведение.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b2-net)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ возможный, но здесь скорее XY-проблема, так как при наличии у ЦБР API, HTML парсить совсем не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- HTML - это не регулярная структура, поэтому парсить HTML регулярками - очень медленно и сложно. Лучше использовать готовый парсер, например `HtmlAgilityPack`.
- `WebClient` устарел, лучше использовать `HttpClient` вместо него.

При том у вас большая регулярка получает только одну валюту, но можно загрузить все.

Для хранения данных валюты, полученных из таблицы, я создал класс

```cs
public class Currency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Далее, я установил 2 NuGet пакета

- **HtmlAgilityPack** - сам парсер
- **Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack** - его расширение `QuerySelector`

`QuerySelector` принимает на вход тот же синтаксис запроса, который используется в `querySelector` в JavaScript.

Получился вот такой код:

```cs
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
```

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            double amount = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            List<Currency> currencies = await GetCurrenciesAsync();
            Currency usd = currencies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "USD");
            double usdValue = usd.Value / usd.Quantity;
            richTextBox1.Text = (usdValue * amount).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task<List<Currency>> GetCurrenciesAsync()
    {
        string html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes = doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll(".data tbody tr");
        List<Currency> currencies = new List<Currency>();
        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            string[] cells = node.QuerySelectorAll("td").Select(x => x.InnerText).ToArray();
            if (cells.Length == 5)
            {
                currencies.Add(new Currency
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(cells[0]),
                    Name = cells[1],
                    Quantity = int.Parse(cells[2]),
                    Text = cells[3],
                    Value = double.Parse(cells[4])
                });
            }
        }
        return currencies;
    }
}
```

Ввожу в `textBox1` число `2`, получаю вывод в `richTextBox1` - `154,5518`. При этом все валюты загружены, можно курс любой валюты получить и использовать точно таким же образом.

---

Но с ЦБР можно обойтись без парсинга HTML - у них [есть API](https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/#json). Можно создать классы для хранения данных, полученных из JSON и распарсить одной  строчкой кода с помощью NuGet пакета **Newtonsoft.Json** или, если у вас .NET Core 3.1 или новее, то с помощью встроенного в фреймворк JSON парсера `System.Text.Json`.

Answer (score 1):

Не самое хорошее решение использовать регулярки для парсинга HTML страниц. При любом изменении контента страницы ваша регулярка перестанет работать. Посмотрите в сторону - [html-agility-pack](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack)

Если говорить о вашем решение то вы не учли несколько моментов:

1. Экранировать символ '/'
2. Наличие спецсимволов между тегами новых строк

Если исправлять ваше решение, то регулярное выражение может выглядеть так:

```
<tr>\W*<td class=\"\">840<\/td>\W*<td class=\"\">USD<\/td>\W*<td class=\"\">1<\/td>\W*<td class=\"\">Доллар США<\/td>\W*<td class=\"\">(.*?)\W*<\/td>\W*<\/tr>
```

UPD: Что бы не было разночтений приведу код на C#

```
        var html = @"
        <tr>
        <td class="""">840</td>
        <td class="""">USD</td>
        <td class="""">1</td>
        <td class="""">Доллар США</td>
        <td class="""">77,2759</td>
        </tr>";
    
    
        var result = Regex.Match(html, "<tr>\\W*<td class=\"\">840<\\/td>\\W*<td class=\"\">USD<\\/td>\\W*<td class=\"\">1<\\/td>\\W*<td class=\"\">Доллар США<\\/td>\\W*<td class=\"\">(.*?)\\W*<\\/td>\\W*<\\/tr>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

        if (result.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"full match: {result.Groups[0].Value}");
            Console.WriteLine($"dollar rate: {result.Groups[1].Value}");
        }
```

Comment: В вашей строке надо либо экранировать все '\', либо убрать все экранирования и поставить '@' перед строкой

Comment: При вводе вашей строки, появляется много. ошибок.

Comment: Добавил пример на C#

Comment: @NightBPhoenix Так как у вас все грубо завязано на контент, то нет смысла в регулярке указывать все данные из <tr>. Достаточно будет грубой и короткой записи: `Regex.Match(textData, @"Доллар США</td>\s*<td.*>(.*?)</td>")`

Answer (score 1):

Использовать регулярки для парсинга - не самая лучшая идея. ([You can't parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/13234130)).

Но если вы хотите, то используйте `@` перед строкой, учитывайте пробельные символы и уберите `class=""`, потому что там нет такого:

```cs
Regex.Match(textData, 
       @"<tr>\s*<td>840</td>\s*<td>USD</td>\s*<td>1</td>\s*<td>Доллар США</td>\s*<td>(.*?)</td>\s*</tr>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит под такие задачи использовать регулярки (см. [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/213987)), стоит использовать парсеры html такие как AngleSharp или HtmlAgilityPack.

Ваш пример на AngleSharp:

```
var source = @"<html><body><table><tr>
       <td class="""">840</td>
       <td class=""myclass"">USD</td>
       <td class="""">1</td>
       <td class="""">Доллар США</td>
       <td class="""">77,2759</td>
    </tr></table></body></html>";

var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.ParseDocument(source);

var currency = document.QuerySelector("td.myclass");
Console.WriteLine(currency.TextContent);
```

Comment: использовать двойные ковычки внутри двойных ковычек не самая хорошая идея. Из-за этого использования в больших программах может произойти беда. Случилось однажды, пока делал мини-проект с 240 строками

Comment: @NightBPhoenix Это фрагмент скрипта в linqpad, он умеет по правому клику вставлять строку автоматически добавив кавычки. Разумеется в реальных проектах такого не будет.