# c# как отправить post запрос со своими данными

Tags: c#, post

только начал изучать c# и не могу понять как отправить post запрос со своими данными, допустим я хочу на сайте зарегистрироваться и там при нажатие на кнопку продолжить отправляется данные в post а в post данные хранятся в Data:

```
password: "здесь мой пароль"
login: "здесь моя почта:"
```

как мне отправить post запрос через c# со своими данными?

Comment: Зависит а) от сайта и б) программ для подключения масса. Начиная от встроенных средств языка (устаревший низкоуровневый WebRequest и новые HttpClient / WebClient ) и заканчивая [парсерами Html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/213987) типа anglesharp или HtmlAgilityPack или кучей других. Тема широкая, начните с чего угодно, потихоньку подберёте себе нужный тулсет.

Comment: Я бы хотел добавить совет: используйте RestSharp. Библиотека давно развивается, есть масса примеров. Можно кодить  как в синхронной, так и в асинхронной парадигме.

Comment: @S.H. хорошо прислушаюсь