# Как указывать заголовки для пост запроса для https://kad.arbitr.ru/Kad/SearchInstances?

Tags: c#, winforms, https

Хочу написать программу которая будет открывать нужное дело по его id(например А84-1724/2021)
Написал такой код, но выдает вот это(фото). Хотя с помощью фиддлера все нормально(результат фиддлера в в виде фото).
Мне кажется нужно указать User Agent и другое, но как?

Фиддлер
[image: Результат фиддлера]

Программа
[image: Результат программы]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       Dictionary<string, string> Params = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
       {"User-Agent:" , "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36" },
      { "CaseNumbers:", "[А84-1719/2021]" },
      { "Count:", "25" },
      { "Courts:", "[]" },
      { "DateFrom:", "null" },
      { "DateTo:", "null" },
      { "Judges:", "[]" },
      { "Page:", "1" },
      { "Sides:", "[]" },
      { "WithVKSInstances:", "false" },
        };
        var result = await GetRequest("https://kad.arbitr.ru/Kad/SearchInstances", Params);
        var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\forgu_000\Desktop\Новый текстовый документ.txt", response);
    }

    static async private Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequest(string Addres, 
    Dictionary<string,string> Params)
    {
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(Addres);
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Params);
        return await http.PostAsync(uri, content);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша основная и **непреодолимая проблема** в целом не в заголовках, хотя как добавить заголовок, я оставлю в коде. Проблема здесь в куках. Дело в том, что сайт загружает сборку WebAssembly - который компилируется и исполняется браузером. Суть его работы в отношении текущей задачи - установка куки типа `wasm=7eed8209dad760c9b99d033aef554062`, где значение куки, как я узнал из декомпилированных исходников - MD5 хэш. А вот хэш чего - это мне уже в отведенное время узнать не удалось.

Куку эту можно получить из обычного браузера, для этого нужно открыть страницу с формой поиска, открыть консоль браузера, ввести в консоли `document.cookie` и вам отобразятся все куки, хранящиеся в веб-странице, в том числе и `wasm`. Далее забрать значение этой куки себе в код, и какое-то время, быть может несколько минут она таки будет работать.

Вторая ваша проблема, что вы пытаетесь запостить `form-urlencoded`, а вроде-как невооруженным глазом видно, что надо постить JSON. Я взял более-менее полный запрос к серверу из формы, отправил, взял JSON и вставил в с Visual Studio как класс. Получился следующий код для формирования данных поискового запроса.

```cs
public class SearchQuery
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string[] Courts { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
    public Side[] Sides { get; set; }
    public Judge[] Judges { get; set; }
    public string[] CaseNumbers { get; set; }
    public bool WithVKSInstances { get; set; }
}

public class Side
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public bool ExactMatch { get; set; }
}

public class Judge
{
    public string JudgeId { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Далее вот такой код позволит отправить верный запрос

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Это больше не нужно
        // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36");
    }

    private async void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery
        {
            CaseNumbers = new string[] { "А84-1719/2021" },
            Count = 25,
            Courts = Array.Empty<string>(),
            DateFrom = null,
            DateTo = null,
            Judges = Array.Empty<Judge>(),
            Page = 1,
            Sides = Array.Empty<Side>(),
            WithVKSInstances = false
        };
           
        try
        {
            string result = await PostJsonAsync("https://kad.arbitr.ru/Kad/SearchInstances", query);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\forgu_000\Desktop\Новый текстовый документ.txt", result);
            MessageBox.Show("Успех!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> PostJsonAsync<T>(string url, T obj)
    {
        using HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Content = content;
        // вот сюда вам нужно вставить тот самый MD5 из браузерной куки
        request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "wasm=7eed8209dad760c9b99d033aef554062");
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
        return await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

И вы получите в `result` HTML страницу. Далее вам останется только прочитать, [Как распарсить HTML в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/373567) и достать нужные вам значения.

Мне жаль, что не смогу помочь. Сайт хорошо защищен от ботов.

Comment: Но выдает: "Код состояния ответа не указывает на успешное выполнение 451"

Comment: @ForgeStudio https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_451 чего-то еще вам не хватает. Вы подключили `Form1_Load`? Но как добавлять заголовки я вам показал.

Comment: Я не понял как его подключить, но вроде ошибку с дизайнером не выдает

Comment: @ForgeStudio Зайдите в дизайнер, выделите форму, справа в свойтвах формы выберите события (кнопка с молнией), найдите в списке `Load`, выберите для события `Form1_Load`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, сразу не заметил. Но проблему это не решило.

Comment: @ForgeStudio Поставьте точку останова на строчку, где заголовок добавляется, если она выполняется, точка останова сработает, тогда всё ок. Далее смотрите в фидлере, каких еще вам заголовков не хватает.

Comment: Сработало, если я все правильно понял.
Вот заголовки, если удалить какое то из них, не работает
https://ibb.co/6FRmNnF

Comment: @ForgeStudio там на самом деле много приколов, и я пытаюсь сейчас разобраться, как всё сделать по уму. Но у меня получилось заставить это работать. И проблема вообще не в заголовках, точнее да, в заголовке Cookie, а еще точнее в куке `wasm`, но ее значение генерит WebAssembly сборка. Если получится, я покажу, как запустить код в сборке, если же нет - покажу как объехать. Но придется подождать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @ForgeStudio мне жаль, но не получилось взломать защиту. Кстати, там еще поддерживается механизм капчи, то есть если часто долбать сервер запросами, он выдаст капчу, и на этом автоматизация превратится в полуавтоматизацию. В любом случае, я скинул в ответ рабочий код, которому если дать рабочую куку, то удастся получить ответ от сервера.

Comment: Такое вообще возможно написать?

Comment: @ForgeStudio возможно всё. Вопрос, какой ценой. Я бы может за месяц управился. Там 30000 строк дизассемблированного кода просто, который и без того читать не так просто. Пока я сделал всё, что мог.

Comment: @ForgeStudio можно правда попробовать эту защиту не взломать, а объехать. Встроить в приложение настоящий браузер, на выбор `WebView2` (новый Edge) или `CefSharp` (Chromium). Открыть страницу с формой в браузере и управляя браузером заполнять форму и жать кнопку. Окно браузера при этом не обязательно показыать в интерфейсе.

Comment: Вообще изначально задумка была чтобы дело открывалось в интерфейсе. Но насколько это все будет быстро? Я про WebView2/CefSharp.

Comment: но почему тогда с помощью фиддлера все получается?

Comment: @ForgeStudio потому что вы в запрос куку из браузера вставляете. Это вроде логично. При точно тех же условиях и код что в ответе будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, но все равно выдает 451. Даже с вставленным wasm,

Comment: @ForgeStudio вставленный работает всего несколько минут.

Comment: Она даже это время не работает.

Comment: Код правильный, но все равно что то не так. Кто то сказал что нужно включить впр, но незнаю зачем.
https://pastebin.com/Zf4j4UBM

Comment: @ForgeStudio этот сайт себя странно ведет, это верно. Но вот прямо сейчас с использованием именно этого кода, вот прямо из ответа скопипастил, вставил куку `request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "wasm=ce4a2cfb165b9522790447e12205aca0");`, и получил нормальный ответ.

Comment: @ForgeStudio ваш код выглядит нормально. Форматирование только немного сбито, затрудняет чтение.

Comment: Может не то копирую? Я копирую id, нажимаю поиск, копирую wasm вставляю сначало id потом wasm, но все равно не то.
https://ibb.co/VwZJjNr

Comment: @ForgeStudio всё верно по идее. Но можно еще просто вкладку консоль открыть и сделать как я в ответе написал.

Comment: Делаю тоже самое, но результата нету. https://youtu.be/fhrsf-2I2cA

Comment: @ForgeStudio браузер использует прокси? соединение должно быть прямое как в браузере, так и в приложении.

Comment: https://ibb.co/vHV5SbV вроде вообще не использую

Comment: @ForgeStudio у меня больше нет идей. Единственная разница между тем, что делаете вы, и тем что делаю я - это тип браузера, у меня Firefox.

Comment: Скачал браузер Firefox, но все равно не работает. Спасибо за советы

Comment: @ForgeStudio ах, да, у меня .NET 5.

Comment: Успех! Просто перешел на .NET 5

Comment: @ForgeStudio ну значит есть разница в поведении `HttpClient`, которая влияет на ответ сервера. В чем именно разница, надо фиддлером смотреть. Отличия отправляемого пакета из .NET 5 и .NET Framework.