# Парсер картинки, С#

Tags: c#, парсер

В html коде присутствует ссылка на картинку, которую необходимо сохранить пользователю в определённую директорию.
Код:

```
<h1 class="title"></h1>
      <div class="imghd"><img src="xxx.jpg" width="850" height="1200" vspace="1" hspace="1" alt="" /></div> 
</div>
```

Программа должна среди всего html кода выбирать заданный source и сохранять картинку в директорию, которую пользователь введет через консоль.
Какими методами возможно решить эту задачу?

Comment: `получать картинку по определённому URL` ... `html код странички остаётся неизменным` начали с одной задачи, закончили другой. Попробуйте перефрзировать вопрос + добавить ваши попытки решить свою задачу.

Comment: В том-то и дело, мне не совсем ясно с чего приступить. Мне необходим источник для изучения, а не готовое решение. (Перефразировал, дал более конкретный набор инструкций).

Comment: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/179763)

Comment: Ну, разделите текст по кавычкам и в получившемся массиве найдите элемент заканчивающийся на `.jpg`. Что то типа: `text.Split('"').ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndWith(".jpg")`

Comment: Ну если необходимо универсальное решение, то я бы использовал Selenium, удобный пакет под C# имеется. И в документации как раз есть пример, который решает конкретно Вашу задачу.