# Найти значение в элементе (selenium) C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, chromedriver

Всем привет, нужно найти значение в элементе, а конкретнее "730", в этом участке

```html
<a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/730/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive/?snr=1_7_7_230_150_1" data-ds-appid="730" data-ds-itemkey="App_730" data-ds-tagids="[1663,1774,3859,3878,19,5711,5055]" data-ds-descids="[2,5]" data-ds-crtrids="[4]" onmouseover="GameHover( this, event, 'global_hover', {&quot;type&quot;:&quot;app&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:730,&quot;v6&quot;:1} );" onmouseout="HideGameHover( this, event, 'global_hover' )" class="search_result_row ds_collapse_flag ds_owned sih_owned" data-gpnav="item">
            <div class="col search_capsule"><img src="https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/730/capsule_sm_120.jpg?t=1623182945" srcset="https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/730/capsule_sm_120.jpg?t=1623182945 1x, https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/730/capsule_231x87.jpg?t=1623182945 2x"></div>
            <div class="responsive_search_name_combined">
                <div class="col search_name ellipsis">
                    <span class="title">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
                    <p>
                        <span class="platform_img win"></span><span class="platform_img mac"></span><span class="platform_img linux"></span>                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col search_released responsive_secondrow">21 авг. 2012</div>
                <div class="col search_reviewscore responsive_secondrow">
                                            <span class="search_review_summary positive" data-tooltip-html="Очень положительные<br>88% из 5,625,994 обзоров положительные.">
                                </span>
                                    </div>


                <div class="col search_price_discount_combined responsive_secondrow" data-price-final="138199">
                    <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col search_price  responsive_secondrow">
                        Бесплатно                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div style="clear: left;"></div>
        <div class="ds_options"><div></div></div></a>
```

Пробовал `IWebElement AppID = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-ds-appid]/@data-ds-appid"));`(Не работает) и `IWebElement AppID = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-ds-appid]"));`, но выдаёт "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
21 авг. 2012 Бесплатно"

Comment: `не то что нужно` теперь нужно догадаться, что выдает и что нужно?

Comment: Зачем вам для стима вдруг понадобился селениум... Вот поражают всегда такие решения. По поводу вопроса, ищите то, что уникально, класс, ID, другое значение, например `data-gpnav="item"`, ищите по нему, если он один на странице, то даст вам нужное, если нет, найдите уникальное, либо уникальный набор значений и ищите по нему.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/373567

Comment: Мне нужны не URL, а именно значение "730"

Comment: Ну так обращацтесь к нужному атрибуту у найденной ноды, а не к InnerText

Comment: Ну вот я и пытаюсь

Comment: `Ну вот я и пытаюсь` - где? Где ваши попытки взять именно атрибут? Также вы ведь понимаете, что этот 730 находится везде, вплоть до ссылки открытой страницы. Также вы мне не ответили про селениум, зачем он вам, если со стимом можно легко подружиться при помощи простых POST/GET запросов?

Comment: Пробовал взять этот атрибут через xpath, я без понятия как можно получить список игр с фильтрами через POST/GET, извините что только начал программировать и создаю свои заявку тут

Comment: `список игр` - какой список, с какой страницей вы работаете и что хотите именно получить? `Пробовал взять этот атрибут через xpath` - `XPath` не берет артибуты, он берет ноду, из которой вы уже достаете нужную вам информацию (аля `.GetArtitubute("имя");` (или как там в селениуме)).

Comment: Хочу получить список игр, с appID и ценой, в категории "Игры", до 150Р, с фильтром "Для одного игрока", цена по возрастанию, работаю с магазином стим, страница поиска. За `.GetArtitubute` спасибо

Comment: @HooK Вот, [самое простое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NvrRxE), что я бы на вашем месте сделал, а еще лучше, поискал бы API (я чет не нашел), который отвечает за поиск. В любом случае, селениум вам не нужен от слова совсем!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо большое, вы считай Америку мне открыли, буду дальше работать с вашим кодом, удачи!