# Как в c# преобразовать строку с шаблонным html-кодом в объект класса?

Tags: c#

У меня есть некоторое количество html-кодов, соответствующих одному шаблону (как на картинке 1). Я хочу преобразовывать его в объект моего класса без использования сторонних библиотек. Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм того, как это можно реализовать. Мой класс будет выглядеть примерно так, как показано на картинке 2.

[image: Картинка 1: html-формат]

[image: Картинка 2: как должен выглядеть мой класс]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/220553

Comment: Без использования сторонних библиотек: 1. Использовать методы класса string для работы с текстом.  Страдать. 2. Использовать регулярные выражения. Страдать.

Comment: а можно поинтересоваться, чего вы не хотите тиспользовать торонние библиотеки?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии! Сторонние библиотеки использовать не буду, потому что хочу сам все сделать "своими руками". Буду пробовать решить задачу через классы string и Regex...

Comment: Есть прикольные сложные инструменты для решения вашей задачи, которые самостоятельно писать - дело неблагодарное. .NET кстати тоже - набор библиотек. Для работы с HTML есть 2 крутые библиотеки в NuGet - `HtmlAgilityPack` и `AngleSharp`, выберите любую. Познакомьтесь с ней. Regex для HTML не подходит, потому что парсить нерегулярные данные регуляркой - это своего рода никому не нужный изврат. Пляски со строками тоже особо пользы вам не принесут. "Вам шашечки или ехать?"

Comment: Хотите пример кода, разбирающего html - вот к примеру исходники HtmlAgilityPack https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/tree/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.2.php - System.Xml, нативно, без сторонних библотек, но время какое-то займёт. Если будет требовать: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> - можно руками добавить.

Comment: Приведённый Вами XML/HTML не содержит синтаксических ошибок? Я про неэкранированные кавычки в значении атрибута body.

Comment: Нет. С кавычками проблем не должно быть.