# HttpClient не видит ответ json

Tags: c#, json, get, httpclient

Отправляю get запрос через HttpCleent C#, в ответе приходит json файл. Но при прочтении json

"JObject responseJs = JObject.Parse(result);"

вылетает ошибка. >>

"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.""

У меня несколько таких методов, в одном json отлично читается, а во втором вообще не видит. Разными манипуляциями понял, что json файл вообще не читается. Если посмотреть через fiddler, то json там есть.

Кто нибудь знает в чем может быть проблема?

---

```
    static CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    public string cookie { get; set; }
    public string userAgent { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }

    string page = "angebote/mercedes-benz-a-140-classic-klima-sitzheizung-export-export-benzin-blau-1fa8a922-22df-4a50-b819-2cec1e3c22ec?lastSeenGuidPresent=true&cldtsrc=listPage&cldtidx=1&topspot_dealer_id=20423&topspot_algorithm=exp-98-topspot-fullfilter-recommended-withoutfilterloosening&topspot_recommender_bucket=bucket1&common_test_cxp_web_9=98_noloosefilter";

    public void GetInfo(string page)
    {
        var baseAdress = new Uri("https://www.autoscout24.de");

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        { CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
          AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,             
        })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", userAgent);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DNT", "1");

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://www.autoscout24.de/lst?sort=standard&desc=0&ustate=N%2CU&atype=C&cy=D&ocs_listing=include&page=2&search_id=4w7uduceiw");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua", "Not;ABrand\";v=\"99\",\"Google Chrome\";v=\"97\",\"Chromium\";v=\"97\"");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "www.autoscout24.de");

                cookie = "asfasfasf=safas;asfasfasf=safas;asfasfasf=safas;"; //куки ни на что не влияют

                string[] cookies = cookie.Split(';');
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] cookieArgs = cookies[i].Split('=');
                    cookieContainer.Add(baseAdress, new Cookie(cookieArgs[0], cookieArgs[1]));
                }

                var response = client.GetAsync(baseAdress + page).Result;     
        
                string res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                  
                //Здесь возникает ошибка
                JObject responseJs = JObject.Parse(response.ToString());
                result = responseJs.ToString();
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: С WebClient такая же ситуация, отоброжается html код страницы, но не json строка. В fiddler так же есть json строка

Comment: Ну, значит по этой ссылке битый JSON, либо вовсе приходит не он. А вот что приходит, как, от куда, тут уж извините, нам от куда знать? Может вы заголовок не указываете нужный, можете еще что.

Comment: У меня два идентичных метода, в одном все получается, во втором изменена только ссылка и в нем не приходит json, но в fiddler он есть. Только программа его не видит

Comment: Без конкретики тут сложно что-либо сказать. Судя по ошибке парсера - вам, вероятнее всего, приходит в ответе HTML. Но это лишь догадка

Comment: Все заголовки правильные, адресс тоже. В fidler запрос полностью рабочий, все данные отправляются и приходит нужный ответ, в том числе json файл. Я использую Newtonsoft.json, кажется в нем проблема.                     

                    var response = await client.GetAsync(baseAdress);
                    result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    JObject responseJs = JObject.Parse(result);   //Здесь возникает ошибка
                    result = responseJs.ToString();   

Если прочитать ответ, то в нем только html код страницы, но нету json

Comment: @DmitriyEptas ну значит эта ссылка требует другого подхода. Давайте нам код, ссылку, делайте минимальный самодостаточный пример, который мы сможем запустить у себя, без этого, ваш вопрос попросту не имеет смысла, ибо нам остаётся лишь гадать что у вас там и как.

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы не про [этот JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mopgk.png) видный в Fiddler говорите? Если да, то какой же это JSON то? Это HTML, внутри которого есть JSON данные, а значит и парсить вам надо сначала HTML, вытягивая от туда JSON, а уж затем делать десериализацию JSON. Если же речь не про этот JSON, то я по указанной ссылке его не вижу.

Comment: Нет, вот этот https://ibb.co/F3DSDh4

Comment: Ну так это фишка Fiddler, который за вас выдрал данные из HTML. Нажмите `Raw` или `TextView`, увидите там HTML, который отдает вам сайт.

Comment: А как мне так же "выдрать" этот json? В другом таком же методе берется список ссылок с обьявлениями, так же через json, и все работает. В этом методе уже берется информация уже об обьявлении. Возможно в этом проблема

Comment: "в другом методе" - мне это не говорит о чем-либо. "как выдрать" - [Как парсить HTML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/220553).