# Как спарсить данные со страницы?

Tags: c#

Как с данной страницы: https://labofspeed.ru/tuning/uaz/pickup.html получить следующую информацию:

1. Марка
2. Модель
3. Поколение
4. Двигатель
5. Тип двигателя
6. Цену

Куда смотреть, не понимаю как его распарсить

Использую AngleSharp

Upd как мне получить данные из input?

Comment: Там используется простой API. Первым делом, вам надо получить HTML страницы, там вы [найдете](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPtXi.png) марку, модель, поколение и их ID (которые понадобятся потом). Далее вы отправляете GET запрос на адрес `/ajax_auto.php?type=modification_1c&cartype=6&carmark=120&carmodel=877&cargeneration=1697`, подставляя все нужные id, тем самым получите доступные двигатели. Тип движка, это значение `fueltypeid`, а их расшифровка также [в HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMbWN.png).

Comment: Осталась цена, она также по API получается (`/ajax_auto.php?type=catalog&cartype=6&carmark=120&carmodel=877&cargeneration=1697&carmodification=4731&options=13`), естественно подставляем все свои значения. Последнее значение `options`, там через запятую указываете id нужных опций (их я надеюсь сможете сами получить, также, через API). Ну и собственно, примеры: [как парсить HTML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/220553), [как находить запросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), ну а отправку GET, я думаю сами поймете.