# найти все страницы сайта C#

Tags: c#, html, url

есть задание :

- приложение должно найти все URL-адреса (html-документы) на веб-сайте, сканируя все страницы (без использования sitemap.xml)
- приложение должно возвращать, сколько URL-адресов было найдено в sitemap.xml и сколько URL-адресов было найдено при сканировании веб-сайта.

можете подсказать что стоить изучить чтобы понять как с этим работать ?

Comment: Что означает "html-документы"? `.html` файлы на диске? Если да, то открывайте директорию, забирайте оттуда все файлы и далее берите из них данные любым [удобным для вас способом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/220553).

Comment: имелось ввиду найти список всех url адресов что есть на сайте , по типу .....com/faq , ....com/readme и всё что есть 
спасибо , скинули вроде то что надо , посмотрю разберусь

Comment: @hekeemje задание может быть невыполнимым из-за get запросов, например `site.com/search.php?q=***` или `site.com/forum.php?thread=***`, т.к. вам нужно будет выдирать странички и ссылки с них рекурсивно - нужно будет ограничить глубину поиска. Хорошая программа-пример: `Extreme Picture Finder`, рекурсивно ходит и парсит странички, выдирая ссылки на изображения, настраивается глубина поиска, фильтр ссылок, и параметры контента. Попробуйте её поюзайте, загоните свои параметры поиска (или модифицируйте готовые), лучше поймёте поставленную задачу и принципы её решения.

Answer (score 3):

1. Необходимо спарсить код каждой страницы
2. собрать все ссылки с кода
3. откинуть ссылки ведущие на внешние ресурсы
4. откинуть ссылки которые ты получал уже раньше и которые ты уже проверил
5. перейти по каждой из ссылок и повторить все прошлые пункты

но вообще такие программы уже существуют их достаточно много. Не имеет смысла писать что-то свое.

гугл: "скачать все страницы сайта"

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что у автора вопроса это учебное задание - в хорошем смысле. То есть, смысл не в том, чтобы получить ответ, а в том, чтобы научиться это делать. Авто вопроса, можете ли Вы подтвердить или опровергнуть это утверждение?

Comment: @S.H. да, это тестовый таск для одной компании чтобы попасть на курсы к ним, то для меня главное не получить эти все html страницы , а разобраться как это сделать самому и всё что для этого надо