# Парсинг и взаимодействие с элементами сайта

Tags: c#, парсер

подскажите в каком направлении двигаться, про какие библиотеки почитать, что бы решить мою задачу.

Мне необходимо, через консольное приложение на c#.
Поработать с некоторыми элементами сайта, например обратиться к выпадающим спискам и выбрать там необходимое значение, после выбора необходимых значение обратиться к кнопке, которая на этом сайте генерирует эксель файл и он скачивается.
В идеале чтобы окно браузера даже не открывалось,
мне это нужно для рутинной, ежедневной задачи, нужно чтобы в фоне работало.

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/220553), остальное зависит от конкретной задачи (JSON, соккеты и прочее).

Comment: класс `HttpClient`, пакет HtmlAgilityPack, асинхронное программирование

Comment: Решил попробовать через GET запросы, но зная GET запрос, введя его в строку он не отрабатывает и пишет что Не удается получить доступ к сайту
Веб-страница по адресу https://a8club.app.enes.tech/api/v2/stat/reports/?format=xlsx&office_id=1&type=shop_quantity&from_date=2022-02-01T19:00:00&to_date=2022-02-01T17:36:00, возможно, временно недоступна или постоянно перемещена по новому адресу.

ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: Как отправить GET запрос с параметрами? Мне кажется он не отрабатывает потому что на этом сайте идет проверка на авторизацию, я через приложение Fiddler погонял запросы, там тоже была ошибка сначала пока я не начал передавать параметр Authorization:Token тд.

@aepot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдёт Selenium: 
Плюсы: 
Гибкость.
Обход защиты от ботов. 
Нет проблем с непрогрузкой страниц. 

Минусы:  
Достаточно много жрёт памяти и CPU. 
Это отдельное окно с браузером.

Comment: Не получилось обратиться через него к элементам сайта, у сайта на кнопке или текстбоксе нет ни id, ни  имени класса.

Comment: Используйте XPath и FullXPath

Comment: Серьёзно, невозможно не найти элемент

Comment: Подскажите как обратиться и работать с комбобоксами?

Comment: Ссылку на сайт, посмотрю

Comment: Ссылку давать нет смысла, вы там не зарегаетесь.
Но у меня все получилось, все само авторизуется и выбирает нужные даты на дататайме и в комбобоксах.
начинается качаться файл, и вот тут уже снова нужна ваша помощь.
Можно ли как то поймать (ответ от сайта) скачку файла и в полете переименовать его?

Comment: 1) Вы можете не нажимать на кнопку скачать(Если у вас эта кнопка есть), а скопировать её ссылку и уже через new WebClient().DownLoadFile(string url, string path); задать нужный путь, а в конце пути название.
Так же вы можете(Как заявляет разработчик) имитировать нажатия в кнопку скачивания Element.SedKeys(string path) и он скачается по нужному пути (Я в это не верю...)
2) Каждое скачивание очищать папку Download и смотреть что файл скачался, далее переименовывать и перемещать

Comment: Подскажите, решил использовать Selenium.
Разобрался, все получилось.

Но есть одно когда программа отрабатывает и браузер закрывается остается консольное окно висеть.
Enviroment.Exit(0) или через Process.Kill не закрывает его ни в какую, иногда, но очень редко окно данное само закрывается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133763/discussion-between-yotic-and-ne0n).