# Вместо Record-а в методе GetWebPageShortResultAsync получаю System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FinallyTask.HttpHelper+WebPageShortResult]

Tags: c#, .net

Вместо Record-а в методе GetWebPageShortResultAsync получаю System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[FinallyTask.HttpHelper+WebPageShortResult],нужно как-то это исправить

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace FinallyTask
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(HttpHelper.GetWebPageShortResultAsync(new Uri("https://www.google.com/"), 1, default));

        }

    }

    public static class HttpHelper
    {
        public record WebPageShortResult
        {
            public  string Body { get; set; }
            public  string Title { get; set; }

        }

        public static Uri? TryConvertToHttpUrl(this string t)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t)) return null;
            return Uri.TryCreate(t, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uri) && (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
                ? uri
                : null;
        }


        public static async Task<Uri> GetRedirectedUrlAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, cancellationToken);
            return response.RequestMessage.RequestUri;
        }

        public static async Task<WebPageShortResult> GetWebPageShortResultAsync(Uri uri, int bodyCharCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {

            var client = new HttpClient();
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            string body = "";
            string title = "";
            if (response.Contains("<title>") && response.Contains("<body>"))
            {
                title = response.Substring(response.IndexOf("<title>") + 7);
                title = title.Remove(title.IndexOf("</title>")).Trim();
                body = response.Substring(response.IndexOf("<body>") + 6);
                body = body.Remove(title.IndexOf("</body>")).Trim();
                body = body.Substring(0, bodyCharCount);
            }
            else
            {
                title = "<Title not found>";
                body = "<Body not found>";
            }
            var result = new WebPageShortResult{ Title = title, Body = body };

            return result;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так у вас `GetWebPageShortResultAsync` является асинхронным `Task`'ом, который надо ожидать через `await`, где вы это делаете? Также я советую вам прочитать документацию про `HttpClient`, там вы увидите: `HttpClient предназначен для однократного создания экземпляра и повторного использования в течение всего жизненного цикла приложения.`. Ну а также, советую почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/220553), ибо сейчас вы страдаете ерундой, а не парсите HTML. Ну и последнее - `static` зло! Забудьте про него. Не ленитесь делать полноценные классы!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сделал всё так как вы сказали,но при этом ничего не получаю из метода

Comment: Я не вижу, чтоб в вопросе что-либо изменилось, а значит "сделал всё так как вы сказали" увы, для меня не говорит что-либо. Вот если править тот код, что в вопросе, у вас должно быть нечто такое `static void Main(string[] args)` меняете на `static async Task Main(string[] args)`, ну а вызов `HttpHelper.GetWebPageShortResultAsync` меняете на `await HttpHelper.GetWebPageShortResultAsync`.

Comment: Извиняюсь,это что-то у меня с самим методом