# Парсинг в C# html agility pack

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack

Есть один старый проект, для парсера использовали html agility pack. Этот пакет использовали 7-8 лет назад. Хотел уточнить этот пакет можно сейчас использовать или есть круче него по производительности и по времени. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, до сих пор актуальны все решения, которые написаны [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420355/220553). Если использовали, нравился, устраивал, то и используйте дальше. Ну а если хотите альтернатив, то вон, популярны сейчас CSS селекторы, можете пробовать их (правда как по мне они очень примитивны).

Comment: EvgeniyZ, спасибо за информацию, но я сейчас по гуглил и нашёл, последнюю версию html agility pack вышла почти пол года назад.                                                                                https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/1.11.46#readme-body-tab

Comment: Ну, если для вас 5 месяцев для проекта, который уже больше 10 лет обновляется это повод отказаться от него, сразу паника, то да, ищите альтернативу)

Comment: Понятно, и спасибо что уделили время.